# Match text outside of html tags

Tags: c#, html, regex

Before anyone says it I know I should use a proper parser but for my use case it is better to use a regular expression.

I have the following regex to try and match text outside of html tags:

```
(?<!<[^>]*)(?<Text>.+?)
```

However this seems to be matching the opening bracket of the tag, i.e. `<`. How can I fix this?

Example input:

```html
<span style="color:blue">some <strong>bold</strong> text</span>
```

Expected:

```
some bold text
```

Got:

```
<some <bold< text<
```

[Link to RegexStorm.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%29%28%3F%3CText%3E.%2B%3F%29&i=%3Cspan%20style%3D%22color%3Ablue%22%3Esome%20%3Cstrong%3Ebold%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20text%3C%2Fspan%3E)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `.` that matches any character. Replace it with a negated character class, like `[^<>]` that matches any char but `<` and `>` and use a *greedy* quantifier `*` (to match 0 or more occurrences) or `+` (to match 1 or more occurrences):

```
(?<!<[^>]*)(?<Text>[^<>]*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D%2A%29%28%3F%3CText%3E%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D%2A%29&i=%3Cspan%20style%3D%22color%3Ablue%22%3Esome%20%3Cstrong%3Ebold%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20text%3C%2Fspan%3E)

BTW, using `(?<Text>.+?)` at the end of the pattern only makes the regex engine match 1 char since the `+?` is a lazy quantifier matching 1 or more occurrences but as few as possible (and since 1 is enough, it will always match just 1 char). Usually, there must be some other pattern after such a lazily quantified one, else, it usually does not fetch the right texts.