# Extract text outside html tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract text using `preg_match()` which is not contained in tags like `<p>` or `<img>`. This text is retrieved from a database and I am working in PHP.

```
This should be extracted <p>I do not want this</p> This should be extracted <a>This may appear after other tags and I do not want this</a>
```

I have tried to do `(.*)(<p>|<a>|<\/p>|<\/a>)(.*)` but this will capture everything up till the last tag and the earlier tags are captured together with text outside of tags.

I have tried to search on Stackoverflow like this:
[Match text outside of html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612945/match-text-outside-of-html-tags) but the regex provided has a pattern error when I pasted it in regex101.com.

Would appreciate any help on this, thanks.

Comment: It's better to use a DOM parser, regular expressions for HTML are always fragile.

Comment: For why @barmar is right, see this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/870729

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your reply. As my text is not from a html or xml file per se but from a database, it does not have a body or head tag. I checked that the parser accesses nodes by using getElementsByTagName, but the text I want are not in tags. Is there any way to get the text which are not in tags?

Comment: @claris Are you saying that your database contains HTML markup tags?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner Yes, unfortunately, as I am working on a legacy system, the database contains HTML markup tags.

Comment: @claris I just add the "database" tag, seeing relevance. You'll probably have to update your question containing the db schema, values and the api used to connect with. You could also look into using a [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) in MySQL if that's the RDBMS used, given if that's what you tried rather than PHP.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The fact that the data is in a database is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @claris You can/should still use a DOM parser, even though your data doesn't have the body and head tags.  A full document is not required... a fragment is fine.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I am trying to extract the text in PHP after getting it from the database. I am not too sure how I can use regexp in mysql too. Thanks for replying

Comment: @Brad Ok I will try to use a DOM parser, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get the values that you want. The trick is to wrap the HTML from your database in a (for example) `<div>` tag, and you can then load it into a `DOMDocument` and use `DOMXPath` to search for children of the `<div>` tag which are purely text using the `text()` path:

```
$html = 'This should be extracted <p>I do not want this</p> This should also be extracted <a>This may appear after other tags and I do not want this</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<div>$html</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$texts = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('/div/text()') as $text) {
    $texts[] = $text->nodeValue;
}
print_r($texts);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => This should be extracted
    [1] =>  This should also be extracted 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gHEYr)